# How to get all links and (some of) the link pages categories for a Wikipedia page?

Tags: wikipedia-api

Is it possible for a given Wikipedia page (e.g. [Dolphin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolphin)) to get all links and for every link its categories (at least some, let's say 5 for every link)?
I want to do this in a single query/API call

I tried:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Dolphin&generator=links&prop=categories&gpllimit=20
```

this returns the links, but only categories for one link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query has to work, but shows only 10 categories totally for the whole query because [`cllimit=10`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bcategories) by default. If you set `cllimit=3` again 3 categories will be returned for the whole query:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Dolphin&generator=links&prop=categories&gpllimit=20&cllimit=3
```

**But:** if use `cllimit=max` you will get the categories for every link:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Dolphin&generator=links&prop=categories&gpllimit=20&redirects=true&cllimit=max
```

Also do not forget to use [`&redirects=true`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query) to resolve redirected links, because these pages are without categories.